# Disqus comments disappear after theme change

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, disqus

I've recently changed my Drupal theme, and reinstalled my Disqus comments module. That said, even though all of my URL paths are the same and I've put my correct Disqus username into the configuration, all of the comments for the individual pages are no longer displayed (though they still appear in my Disqus account)?

Comment: Does it work if you change theme back? (without module reinstall)

Comment: @Paradoxetion Nope :/

Comment: Ohh, not cool. Ok, how did you make "reinstall"? Did you also made modules uninstall from the "Uninstall" tab?

Comment: @Paradoxetion No - I simply deleted all of the modules from the modules folder, and dragged the new set in :/

Comment: Uhhhh. That's not the way =). Ok try to run update.php script. Could save you

Comment: @Paradoxetion Lol to be clear: this is a new drupal installation on a new database (I didn't just overwrite the old one). That said, I figured making all of my paths (URLS) the same would just allow disqus to populate the comments back onto the appropriate pages?